# Change color of just one hyperlink on moderncv

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, links

I am using moderncv and I want to change the color of the mail address link in the personal section but I want the rest of the links on my cv to remain blue. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{First name}
\familyname{Last name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}
\mobile{Phone}
\email{Email}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=NavyBlue}}

\begin{document}

\cvitem{Email}{\emaillink{test@gmail.com}}

  \section{Education}
 \cventry{Year}{Degree}{University}{Location}{GPA. \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}{}


\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\href{http://www.google.com}{click me}}}{}{}
\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\url{http://www.google.com}}}{}{}

\end{document}
```

So, I want the test@gmail.com to appear in black and the google ones to remain in blue. Is there a way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to group an additional `\hypersetup` command just for the mail address:

```
\begingroup%
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black}%
\cvitem{Email}{\emaillink{test@gmail.com}}%
\endgroup%
```

---

This prevents another setup of `hyperref` later on.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{First name}
\familyname{Last name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}
\mobile{Phone}
\email{Email}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=NavyBlue}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black}%
\cvitem{Email}{\emaillink{test@gmail.com}}
\endgroup

  \section{Education}
 \cventry{Year}{Degree}{University}{Location}{GPA. \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}{}

\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\href{http://www.google.com}{click me}}}{}{}
\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\url{http://www.google.com}}}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create what you want by redefining the urlcolor in the document. Start with defining it black, and after the personal section change it to NavyBlue. The following code returns a warning because the urlcolor macro is changed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{First name}
\familyname{Last name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}
\mobile{Phone}
\email{Email}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=Black}}

\begin{document}
\cvitem{Email}{\emaillink{test@gmail.com}}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=NavyBlue}
\section{Education}
\cventry{Year}{Degree}{University}{Location}{GPA. \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}{}


\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\href{http://www.google.com}{click me}}}{}{}
\cventry{2012}{test}{test}{\texttt{\url{http://www.google.com}}}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So Christian Hupfer's solution is probably better since it will not have the warnings I suppose.

Comment: This solution didn't give me any warning so it also works great! Thanks

Comment: @Bart: There is no warning.

Comment: Hm, then it is probably my TexnicCenter. Never mind then.